# PHP Form Processing from Dimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, forms, associative-array

I have the following function,

```
<pre>
public function getFree($cp) {
            global $glb_con;

            try {
                $sql = "SELECT p.ID, w.ID, p.fname, p.lname, w.desc FROM weight w 
                INNER JOIN comp t ON w.wcl = t.cmp AND  w.wc = t.cm
                INNER JOIN pers b ON w.ID = b.ID_l 
                INNER JOIN pn p ON b.ID = p.ID 
                AND t.cp=:cp group";  

                $query = $glb_connection->prepare($sql);
                $query->bindValue(':cp',$cp);
                $query->execute();
                $wes = $query->fetchAll();

                // First array Generated from sql1 query 
                    $newCorr = array();
                foreach ($wes as $option) {
                    $wclID = $option['desc'];
                    $nameF = $option['fname'];
                    $nameL = $option['lname'];
                    $id = $option['ID'];
                    $newCorr[$wclID][$id] = $nameL." ".$nameF;
                }

                 $sql2 = "SELECT p.ID, e.enre w.ID, p.fname, p.lname, w.desc FROM weight w 
                INNER JOIN comp t ON w.wcl = t.cmp AND  w.wc = t.cm
                INNER JOIN pers b ON w.ID = b.ID_l 
                INNER JOIN pn p ON b.ID = p.ID 
                INNER JOIN t_ent e ON e.ID = p.ID
                AND t.cp=:cp group";  

                $query = $glb_connection->prepare($sql2);
                $query->bindValue(':ID_cmp',$ID_cmp);
                $query->execute();
                $wes1 = $query->fetchAll();

                //the second array from sql2 query 
                    $newCorrAc = array();
                foreach ($wes1 as $option) {
                    $wc = $option['desc'];
                    $ent = $option['enre'];
                    $nameF = $option['fname'];
                    $nameL = $option['lname'];
                    $id = $option['ID'];
                    $newCorrAc [$wc] [$id] [$ent]= $nameL." ".$nameF;
                }

            //the form will generate after here here
                $html_form = '';

                if(count($newCorr) == 0){

                    $html_form .= '<p>'.boz(_('Not Found!')).'</p>';
                } else {    

                    $html_form .= '<form  id="checkEnt" name="checkEnt" method="post" action="r.php?cp=<?=$cp?>">';
                    $html_form .= '<input type="hidden" value="checkEntrance" name="ent">';
                    $html_form .= '<table class="table zebra-striped table-bordered table-striped span8">';
                    $html_form .= '<tbody>';

                    foreach ($newCorr as $orgKey => $list) { 
                        $html_form .= '<tr><td width="5%">';
                        $html_form .= '<h5>'.$orgKey.'kg</h5>';
                        $html_form .= '</td>
                        <td width="10%">
                        <label class="control-label" for="inputWei">Boxer</label>';  
                        $html_form .= '<select class="input-xlarge" id="input" name="drop[0][]">';   
                        $html_form .= '<option value="">Select</option>';
                        foreach ($list as $key => $value) {
                            $html_form .= '<option value='.$key.'>'.$value.'</option>';

                        } 
                        $html_form .= '</select>
                        </td>
                        <td width="10%">
                        <label class="control-label" for="inputWei">Res</label>
                        <select class="input-xlarge" name="drop[1][]">';
                        $html_form .= '<option value="">Select</option>
                        <option value="en">Ent</option>
                        <option value="re">Res</option>
                        </select>
                        </td>
                        </tr>';
                    }

                    $html_form .= '<tr><td colspan="3">
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type=reset class="btn btn-danger">Reset</button>
                    <button class="btn btn-primary" ID="btnSaveBoxer">Save</button>
                    </div>
                    </td>
                    </tr> 
                    </tbody>
                    </table> 
                    </form>';   
                }             
                echo $html_form;

            } catch(PDOException $e) {
                addError($e->getMessage(), "MySql-Error", "error");
            }
        }
</pre>
```

what it does is exactly ...the First SQL returns array in FetchAll method, and after a bit of change the result will be like this...

// First Query Result array check this line
$newCorr[$wclID][$id] = $nameL." ".$nameF;

```
<pre>
Array
(
    [4-6] => Array
        (
            [87] => haha lala
        )

    [8] => Array
        (
            [25] => sasa baba
            [24] => mama fafa
            [26] => tata lala
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [29] => papa oaoa
            [27] => laha mana
            [30] => salam sara
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [33] => tata kaka
            [32] => lala sasa
            [31] => Papa lama
            [34] => wana michel
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [35] => zaza yaya
            [37] => wana mata
            [36] => Kaku luba
        )

)
</pre>
```

from the above code as you can see, I generate dropdown form, which filled from the above array.

What problem I have faced is, after the customer enter the form data, when I need to populate the form as it is except the customer choice must be selected as default...

So, what i did is i use second SQL2, which generates the following array, this array is exactly what the customer enter it.

// Second Query Result Array
$newCorrAc [$wc] [$id] [$ent]= $nameL." ".$nameF;

```
<pre>
Array
(
    [8] => Array
        (
            [26] => Array
                (
                    [ent] => tata lala
                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [31] => Array
                (
                    [res] => papa lama
                )

        )

) 
</pre>
```

The main question is, how do I be able to fill the forms from his/her previous enter data when the drop down populated again?

In short what i want to do is, the form is submited, and i have link for correction. if clicked it should show the same form except with the entered data previously, that can be get from database.

some Idea please?

Comment: What about adding the loaded data to the `value` of each field? Or for dropdowns, add `selected="selected"` to the option matching the database entry.

Comment: how you mean exactly? can you elaborate a bit???

Comment: You want to prefill the generated form, using the values the customer entered. When generating the form, you can set 'default' values for an **input element**, using the `value` attribute. `<input name="..." value="{$defaultValue}" />`. For **dropdown**, you can add `selected="selected"`. `<option value="val" selected="selected" />`.

Comment: are you telling me that if i add selected="selected" to my dropdown works? could you please check the above cod and suggest where i should put this and how it gona work? I appriciate ur help....

Comment: Well, only add `selected="selected"` if that value SHOULD be selected, ofcourse. So you'll have to check if it should be selected, then add it. Else, don't add it. And I'll have a look at it ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I dug through your code. When changing the form generation loop:

```
foreach ($list as $key => $value) {
    $html_form .= '<option value='.$key.'>'.$value.'</option>';

}
```

to this:

```
// This will contain selected="selected" html code for your
// second column dropdown menu. This way seemed to be the clearest for me.
$typeEntSelected = '';
$typeResSelected = '';

foreach ($list as $key => $value) {
    $html_form .= '<option value="'.$key.'"';
    if (isset($newCorrAc[$orgKey][$key])) {
        // Select last user input in Boxer dropdown
        $html_form .= ' selected="selected"';

        $userEntry = $newCorrAc[$orgKey][$key];
        if (array_key_exists('ent', $userEntry)) {
            $typeEntSelected = ' selected="selected"';
        } elseif (array_key_exists('res', $userEntry)) {
            $typeResSelected = ' selected="selected"';
        }
    }
    $html_form .= '>'.$value.'</option>';
}
```

and a little bit lower, change your second column dropdown generation code from this

```
$html_form .= '<option value="">Select</option>
<option value="en">Ent</option>
<option value="re">Res</option>
</select>
</td>
</tr>';
```

to this. *The second and third row in the block are changed.*

```
$html_form .= '<option value="">Select</option>
<option value="en"' . $typeEntSelected . '>Ent</option>
<option value="re"' . $typeResSelected . '>Res</option>
</select>
</td>
</tr>';
```

it selects 'tata lala' in the *8kg Boxer* field, and 'Papa lama' in the *2kg Boxer* field. Now it also selects "ent" and res in the second field. The rest is unselected. Is is this behaviour that you're after?

Comment: Hi UrGuardian4ngel, thanks for your help...it seems working well except the other drop down which is this part... It doesn't look picking up the corresponding entry. in other word when 'Papa lama is selected' the other drop down in front of the name should be pick up this '[res] => papa lama' res...very important..but we are in tip just need some amendment...idea lease?

Comment: waiting if you have any idea?

Comment: how do i handle this part?  $html_form .= '</select>
                        </td>
                        <td width="10%">
                        <label class="control-label" for="inputWei">Res</label>
                        <select class="input-xlarge" name="drop[1][]">';
                        $html_form .= '<option value="">Select</option>
                        <option value="en">Ent</option>
                        <option value="re">Res</option>
                        </select>
                        </td>
                        </tr>';

Comment: Hey sorry... Just came home, after being a whole day out. But yes, that's those boxes are the only thing that select the last entry. Couldn't find the rest in your "user input array" back then :/ But I'll check again... Edit: oh it's just the key. I'll update the answer ;)

Comment: Please do so, there is another select drop down which comes together with first side by side, you solve the first but the second still empty...please help, I am waiting...

Comment: I mean, re-check the code you will see the next drop down which is static, but we can put it in array so that we can use foreach loop. Any way I really appreciate your help. I am just stake...

Comment: It should be solved now. *Edit: the first block has changed a bit too. Apply the 'patch' to your original code in your question, just to be sure.* If it's not fixed yet, please respond within an hour. Tomorrow I'm leaving for a week, without computer or access to the internet, so it'll probably take a while before I can answer. In the other case, you can mark this issue as resolved. Greetz, Michaël.

Comment: That is my men, Thanks hey...you really did it. I appreciate a lot. Please re-visit my account i mostly have some question similar to this....Thanks again.